# Firebase retrieve information once user is logged in

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following database and need some help retrieving the name and address from the user which is logged in currently. 
[image]

I wrote the following code but the information is not showing in the textview

```
public class UserProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseReference userReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    TextView userName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_profile);

        userName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userName);

        ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                    userName.setText(name);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        };
    }
}
```

This is what is currently happening when implementing the ValueEventListener
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
FirebaseUser user=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String userid=user.getUid();
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(userid);

reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

   String address=dataSnapshot.child("address").getValue().toString();
   String name=dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
    userName.setText(name);


 }
 @Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
 });
```

Since your datasnapshot is on the `child(userid)` which is direct child under root node then you don't need to iterate to be able to get the values of the current user.